# Create a Contingency table of Total and Shared Visitors between two buildings

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I need to create a contingency table based on a location, and values should be frequency of visits based on a person's check in.

Below is a sample problem with data:

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [
    ["A", "Building 12", 1],
    ["A", "Building 11", 3],
    ["A", "Building 12", 1],
    ["A", "Building 11", 3],
    ["B", "Building 11", 7],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["ID", "Location", "Visits"])
```

```
        ID  Location    Visits
    0   A   Buidling 12 1
    1   A   Building 11 3
    2   A   Building 12 1
    3   A   Building 11 3
    4   B   Building 11 7
```

Each row indicates a specific day. For example, row 0 shows that visitor A went to Building 12 once on that day and then in row 2, they returned on another day.

I need to understand the flow of people through a particular building. Below is expected output:

```
Location    Building 12 Building 11
Location            
Buidling 12        2    0
Building 11        6    13
```

From the above:

- Building 12: was visited by only person A (in total 2 times)
- Building 11: was visited by person A & B (in total 13 times)
- Building 12: was only visited by person A who did not go to building 11 (hence 0 is placed in top quad)
- Building 11: was visited by both however person A visited Building 11 (hence 6 visits is placed in bottom quad)

That is, Building 11 shared visits with Building 12 X 6.

This is obviously a small, sample and I have many records. I have tried the following:

```py
pd.crosstab(df.Location, df.Location, values=df.Visits, aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

But, it doesn't create a unique list of buildings and visits are not shared.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), and [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from Python standard library's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module:

```py
from itertools import product

# Create new dataframe with total number of visits per building
new_df = (
    df.groupby("Location")
    .sum(numeric_only=True)
    .rename(columns={"Visits": "Total visits"})
)

# Use a temporary dataframe and check for missing values
# -> append new row with 0 for (building 12, B)
tmp = df.groupby(["Location", "ID"]).sum().reset_index()
for location, idx in product(tmp["Location"].unique(), tmp["ID"].unique()):
    if tmp.loc[(tmp["Location"] == location) & (tmp["ID"] == idx)].empty:
        tmp.loc[tmp.shape[0], ["Location", "ID", "Visits"]] = [location, idx, 0]

# Add column to new dataframe with number of shared visits
new_df["Shared visits"] = (
    tmp.groupby("Location")
    .min(numeric_only=True)
    .astype(int)
    .rename(columns={"Visits": "Shared visits"})
)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
             Total visits  Shared visits
Location
Building 11            13              6
Building 12             2              0
```